# Can someone explain why I'm getting segmentation fault 11?

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
int main() {

    typedef struct {

        int recordCount;
        char *firstName;
        char *secondName;
        char *id;
        char *email;

    }student;

    student *students = malloc(sizeof(*students));

    int i = 0;

    while (students[i].firstName[0] != '.'){

        students[i].firstName = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        scanf("%s", students[i].firstName);
        i++;
        students = realloc(students, sizeof(students) * (i + 1));

    }
}
```

When I run it through a for loop it works, I'm pretty sure it's just something silly going on with my while loop.

Comment: you are allocating `sizeof(char*)` which gives you space to just four characters (you are asking for space to store just a pointer value, not an array of characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc` returns a block of uninitialized memory.  So `students[i].firstName` is an uninitialized pointer which you attempt to dereference.  Reading and dereferencing an uninitialized pointer invokes undefined behavior, which in this case manifests as a crash.

When you *do* allocate space for the `firstName` member, you only allocate `sizeof(char*)` bytes for it which is the size of a pointer, not necessarily the length of a string you would want to read.

Create a buffer to read strings into that's big enough for what you might need, then use `strdup` to create a copy to assign to the relevant pointer.

```
student *students = NULL;
int i = 0;
char str[100];

scanf("%99s", str);
while (str[0] != '.'){
    students = realloc(students, sizeof(*students) * (i+1));
    students[i].firstName = strdup(str);
    i++;

    scanf("%99s", str);
}
```

Comment: If `realloc` fails you have lost all the previously allocated students. Better to save the result of realloc to a temporary pointer and check if it is not NULL before going on to the next call.

Answer (score 3):

For a start,

```
students[i].firstName = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

allocates enough space for a character *pointer,* typically four or eight bytes.

While there are some names that *will* fit in that (such as `Pax` or `Bob`), the vast majority probably won't.

You need to allocate enough space for the largest name (and string terminator), such as with:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 100
students[i].firstName = malloc(MAX_NAME_LEN + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of issues in your code.

1. When you are using `malloc`, you actually specify the `data type` and not the `pointer type` which is I believe is not your intent here. If you are specifying a pointer type with `sizeof`, the pointer will point to a memory location having the size of the pointer. This is not what you want in this case.
2. After the line `student *students = malloc ...` . The `students` will point to a memory location which will hold zero values in `firstName`. You need to use malloc for these. Since you are not doing this you are getting a segmentation fault because you are dereferencing an invalid pointer (pointing to location `0`). You are trying to access it first and using `malloc` afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

If you

```
student *students = malloc(sizeof(*students));
```

you are allocating size of one pointer. What you want to do is instead

```
student *students = malloc(sizeof(students));
```

and for the same reason, `students[i].firstName = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*))` quite surely do not have enough memory for your name as well, try `malloc(sizeof(char)*100)` or so.

Comment: I didn't downvote you (someone else got in first) but your first point is wrong - `students` is the pointer, `*students` is the full struct. So that allocation was right. As you point out, the second one is invalid, allocating only enough memory for a pointer. But I'm not a fan of the `sizeof(char) * X` since `char` is *always* of size one.